# How to use Cloudberry Powershell Snap-in (for Amazon S3) from within a scheduled SQL Agent Job?

Tags: sql, powershell, amazon-s3, backup, cloud

I am trying to automate my SQL database backup process. My goal is to use the Cloudberry Powershell cmdlet to give me direct control and access over my S3 buckets. I am able to do this manually but cannot get my SQL jobs to work with this.

According to Cloudberry's installation instructions, I shouldn't have to register the Cloudberry Powershell snap-in if Powershell is already installed. I have found that to be false. I have tried to register it, both 64-bit and 32-bit with no luck.

This works when executed manually/explicitly from the ISE:

```
Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn

$today = Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss" 
$key = "mykeygoeshere"
$secret = "mysecretgoeshere"

$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key $key -Secret $secret
$destination = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path "ProductionBackups/MyClient/log/" | Add-CloudFolder $today
$src = Get-CloudFilesystemConnection | Select-CloudFolder "X:\backups\MyClient\current\"
$src | Copy-CloudItem $destination -filter "log.trn"
```

^ When this command is executed in a SQL Agent job, it fails with this message:

> Executed as user: DB-MAIN\SYSTEM. A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term 'Add-PSSnapin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. '. Process Exit Code -1. The step failed.

I read in [this blog post](http://cmille19.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/sqlps-exe-the-shellid-and-closed-shells/) that SQLPS.exe cannot execute 'Add-PSSnapin' commands? Is that true? I cannot find any clarification on the subject...

how can I automate my SQL backup files to the Amazon S3 cloud? I have tried everything. TNT Drive was a huge waste of time. I am hoping Cloudberry can do it, any tips?

Comment: It looks like the script is being run as the system user. Have you tried manually running the script as the system account? You can launch an instance of Powershell.exe as the system account using the sysinternals tool psexec.exe -i -s "C:\...\powershell.exe". Also why not run it as a Windows scheduled task?

Comment: I ended up running it as a Windows scheduled task and it works fine. I simply cannot get it to execute from a SQL Agent Job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Amazon AWS .Net SDK. You can download it from here:
http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/

Here's the example function to download file from S3:

```
 function DownloadS3File([string]$bucket, [string]$file, [string]$localFile)
{
if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)")
{
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\AWSSDK.dll"
}
else
{
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\AWSSDK.dll"
}

$secretKeyID= $env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
$secretAccessKeyID= $env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

$client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($secretKeyID,$secretAccessKeyID)

$request = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest
$request.BucketName = $bucket
$request.Key = $file
$response = $client.GetObject($request)

$writer = new-object System.IO.FileStream ($localFile ,[system.IO.filemode]::Create)
[byte[]]$buffer = new-object byte[] 4096
[int]$total = [int]$count = 0
do
    {
    $count = $response.ResponseStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)    
    $writer.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
    }
   while ($count -gt 0)

$response.ResponseStream.Close()
$writer.Close() 

echo "File downloaded: $localFile"
}
```

Comment: That's cool and all but I am trying to figure out how to do this using the Cloudberry Powershell cmdlet. This is a powershell and SQL Agent problem. I have looked at the Amazon .NET SDK but my shop that I work in does not want to re-invent cloud software. Cloudberry costs $40 and I cost much more an hour.